# Flex: No progress bar?

Tags: apache-flex, preloader

I have been dealing with this for a few months now. My flex apps are not showing preloaders on many users computers. I thought it was because I was using BrowserManager but I have made a few lately without browser manager. It works fine on my machine but then I walk over to the managers machine and load the page and the app is not there, no preloader, I am standing there looking like an idiot for about 5 minutes and then it pops up. A regular user would not wait this long. Does anyone have any idea why this would happen?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
Today we figured out that while the flex app is blank if you mouse over where the flex app should be it, it pops up immediately but not until you mouse over the spot where the flex app is....What does that mean??

Comment: Does this happen on everyone's computer who's loading the app for the first time?

Comment: Its not the first time, its almost every time! but I don't think its on everyones machine but over half I would say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently since it waits to show until you move your mouse over, a work around I found on the net is adding this:

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('WeddingBandBuilder').focus()">
```

Where WeddingBandBuilder is the ID to the embedded swf.

Answer (score 0):

one of the reasons it maybe working on your machine and not others is that your are using a debug version of the flash player to debug your flex app. Then each time you launch you are almost 100% certain that the swf file is not in cache.

Does the problem still exist if you clear your managers cache before launching the app?

From Adobe site (http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=app_container_4.html)
The download progress bar is not displayed if the SWF file is on your local host or if it is already cached. If the SWF file is not on your local host and is not cached, the progress bar is displayed if less than half of the application is downloaded after 700 milliseconds of downloading.

That still does not 100% explain why it is taking 5min to display the progress bar.